# ERROR TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null.Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made npm run build such a request on vue js. But the answer is this: you can help. but I want to deploy the project with a current error came out.I have a running npm run server.

```
✔  Building for production...
 ERROR  TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\django 5\Новая папка (34)\Новая папка (29)\Новая папка (23) full\vuedjangorest\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\CssDependency.js:12:46)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\django 5\Новая папка (34)\Новая папка (29)\Новая папка (23) full\vuedjangorest\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js:12:45)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\django 5\Новая папка (34)\Новая папка (29)\Новая папка (23) full\vuedjangorest\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\cjs.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vuedjangorest@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vuedjangorest@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Toma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-15T23_16_59_526Z-debug.log
```

my index.html it looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    




    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Open+Sans|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootstraptema.ru/plugins/2016/animate/animate.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-clickaway/2.2.1/vue-clickaway.min.js" integrity="sha512-sOXxDTpOJUOo/TDLL091b1vj4vxZEGVJVImZ/YFGccdhtI9tkXfnuBv9VEQG+MnZ7tt3R+h6r7yZH9APkBD+kg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.0.11/lib/index.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/76a01e3e01.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.5.4/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-7yA/d79yIhHPvcrSiB8S/7TyX0OxlccU8F/kuB8mHYjLlF1MInPbEohpoqfz0AILoq5hoD7lELZAYYHbyeEjag==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body style="background: #f4f4f4;">
    
    <div id="app"></div>

  </body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: What are you using to build this project?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}`

Comment: are you using only babel? or are you using webpack, parcel, etc?

Comment: @evolutionxbox `"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
  ]`

Answer (score 3):

Install the latest webpack
**npm i webpack -g**

Also, locally
**npm i webpack --save**

and finally install
**npm install --save webpack-dev-server** for local installation.

I had the same problem and worked for me.

Comment: This is the right answer!